# how to avoid nested subqueries in SQL

Tags: mysql, performance, subquery, inner-join

I've just added a tagging system to my website and I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way to run scalable queries. Here's a basic working mysql query to return tag matches for a given user:

```
SELECT
   scans.scan_index,
   scans.scan_id,
   scans.archive_folder 
FROM
   tags 
   INNER JOIN
      interpretationtags USING (tagid) 
   INNER JOIN
      interpretations USING (interpretation_id) 
   INNER JOIN
      scans 
      ON scans.scan_id = interpretations.scan_id 
      AND scans.archive_folder = interpretations.archive_folder 
   INNER JOIN
      archives 
      ON scans.archive_folder = archives.archive_folder 
WHERE
   archives.user_id = "google-authd...." 
   AND tags.tag = "tag1"
```

But it gets sticky when I want to query multiple `tags` for the same `scan`. You see, `tags` are present in different `interpretations,` and there are multiple interpretations for each `scan.` Here's a working query for two `tags` using a subquery:

```
SELECT
   a.scan_index,
   a.scan_id,
   a.archive_folder 
FROM
   (
      SELECT
         scans.scan_index,
         scans.scan_id,
         scans.archive_folder 
      FROM
         tags 
         INNER JOIN
            interpretationtags USING (tagid) 
         INNER JOIN
            interpretations USING (interpretation_id) 
         INNER JOIN
            scans 
            ON scans.scan_id = interpretations.scan_id 
            AND scans.archive_folder = interpretations.archive_folder 
         INNER JOIN
            archives 
            ON scans.archive_folder = archives.archive_folder 
      WHERE
         archives.user_id = "google-auth2..." 
         AND tags.tag = "tag1"
   )
   as a 
   INNER JOIN
      interpretations 
      ON a.scan_id = interpretations.scan_id 
      AND a.archive_folder = interpretations.archive_folder 
   INNER JOIN
      interpretationtags USING(interpretation_id) 
   INNER JOIN
      tags USING(tagid) 
WHERE
   tags.tag = "tag2"
```

Since this is running on a LAMP stack, I've written some PHP code to iterate over the `tags` I'd like to include in this AND-style search, building a multi-nested query.  Here's one with three

```
SELECT
   b.scan_index,
   b.scan_id,
   b.archive_folder 
FROM
   (
      SELECT
         a.scan_index,
         a.scan_id,
         a.archive_folder 
      FROM
         (
            SELECT
               scans.scan_index,
               scans.scan_id,
               scans.archive_folder 
            FROM
               tags 
               INNER JOIN
                  interpretationtags USING (tagid) 
               INNER JOIN
                  interpretations USING (interpretation_id) 
               INNER JOIN
                  scans 
                  ON scans.scan_id = interpretations.scan_id 
                  AND scans.archive_folder = interpretations.archive_folder 
               INNER JOIN
                  archives 
                  ON scans.archive_folder = archives.archive_folder 
            WHERE
               archives.user_id = "google..." 
               AND tags.tag = "tag1"
         )
         as a 
         INNER JOIN
            interpretations 
            ON a.scan_id = interpretations.scan_id 
            AND a.archive_folder = interpretations.archive_folder 
         INNER JOIN
            interpretationtags USING(interpretation_id) 
         INNER JOIN
            tags USING(tagid) 
      WHERE
         tags.tag = "tag2"
   )
   as b 
   INNER JOIN
      interpretations 
      ON b.scan_id = interpretations.scan_id 
      AND b.archive_folder = interpretations.archive_folder 
   INNER JOIN
      interpretationtags USING(interpretation_id) 
   INNER JOIN
      tags USING(tagid) 
WHERE
   tags.tag = "tag3"
```

Even 4 nested subqueries runs fast with minimal data, but I just don't see this being a scalable solution when I'm dealing with 100k rows of data. How can I accomplish this without reverting to this ugly inefficient code?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query. In addition, questions about query optimisation always require the EXPLAIN for the given query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to be certain without table structures and sample data, but I think you're going about this in the wrong direction. You should start from scans and find all the appropriate tags, and then filter on those (which should then be a simple `IN` expression):

```
SELECT
   scans.scan_index,
   scans.scan_id,
   scans.archive_folder 
FROM
   scans
   INNER JOIN
      archives 
      ON scans.archive_folder = archives.archive_folder 
   INNER JOIN
      interpretations 
      ON scans.scan_id = interpretations.scan_id 
      AND scans.archive_folder = interpretations.archive_folder 
   INNER JOIN
      interpretationtags USING (interpretation_id) 
   INNER JOIN
      tags USING (tagid) 
WHERE
   archives.user_id = "google-authd...." 
   AND tags.tag IN("tag1", "tag2")
```

Note that based on your `SELECT` field list I don't think you actually need to `JOIN` to `archives` at all.

Comment: Thanks Nick. This is close, but it gets all scans with tag1 OR tag2.

Comment: @UltrasoundJelly so you want scans with tag1 AND tag2? It wasn't 100% clear from your question

Comment: Sorry, AND is the goal.

Comment: You should be able to add `GROUP BY scans.scan_index,
   scans.scan_id,
   scans.archive_folder HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tags.tag) = 2` to the query to achieve that.

Comment: That does work here, but what if there there are two interpretations on the same scan with tag1?

Comment: Because you are grouping only on scan information and counting `DISTINCT tags.tag` that will only give a count of 1.

Comment: One last question.  Why does this query return a different number of rows when I select `count(*)`?

Comment: I suppose that count will always return a factor of two for this query, or a factor of n tags searched.

Comment: @UltrasoundJelly I'm not quite sure what you mean when you say you `select count(*)`?

Comment: Like if the sql started `SELECT count(*) FROM scans...`

Comment: The count probably wouldn't be accurate because you'd get a multiplicative effect where scans had multiple interpretations that had multiple tags. That's why the `HAVING` clause uses `COUNT(DISTiNCT...)`. The count might be a multiple of the number of tags but that's not guaranteed as it depends on how many tags per interpretation there are.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if it would be performant to just get the row numbers when iterating over the mysqli results in php, or would it be better too revamp this code to return an accurate count as well as records.

Comment: @UltrasoundJelly I think that's probably one of those things you can only tell by actually doing it and measuring the results.

Comment: When using `INNER JOIN`, the Optimizer is free to reorder the tables.  (It is, however, a good idea to order them so that a human reader understands what is going on.)  See `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`; it might give you an example of such reordering.

Comment: MySQL vs PHP -- Which would you rather do?  Add one line to the SQL, or add 40 lines of PHP?  Granted, you _understand_ how to write the PHP, and the SQL is an uphill learning curve.  Consider it a learning experience.  And 40 lines of code has more chances of typos, design flaws, etc, etc.